# .htaccess and exact matches

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having trouble rewriting the following:

- mysite.com
- mysite.com/myproduct
- www.mysite.com
- www.mysite.com/myproduct

to **mysite.com/myproduct/**

Whatever I tried, it was either missing rewrites or rewriting other urls.
I'm guessing this should be 4 couples of subsequent Cond and Rule, as I only need exact 4 redirections, but I'm not familiar enough with the syntax an expressions.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't try to rewrite something without a slash to something with a slash - you invite disaster that way. Match your slashes exactly!

Second - rewriting in htaccess is not advised, and works differently than in httpd.conf.

Third - WHY are you rewriting ? What is the Goal ?

If you want all requests for those 4 prefixes to end up on the same web site, make a  new vhost instead, and match that with a Redirect, like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mysite.com
  Redirect /myproduct/ http://mysite.com/myproduct/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.com
  RedirectMatch !^/myproduct/.* http://mysite.com/myproduct/
</VirtualHost>
```